# Kotlin get default hashCode implementation for inherited class

Tags: kotlin, hashcode

Before overriding, each class in Kotlin/JVM has default equals/hashCode implementation. Equals is checking for reference equality with `===`, but hashCode is something else (and I don't know what it is).

I wonder if I can get the default implementation of hashCode back once overriden, consider this example:

```
open class A {
    override fun hashCode(): Int = 1
}

class B : A() {
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        // how can I get the default implementation here?..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't access to super.super methods, but the JVM actually provides a method to get the original hash code value:

```
class B : A() {
    override fun hashCode(): Int = System.identityHashCode(this)
}
```

Comment: You would probably need the `Any?` version on native as I suspect the System object probably isn't exposed there. However I don't think the `Any?` method is available on JVM so you have to use the system version on that platform.